# XCode doesn't finish test build while at "Run Script" phase

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing

When trying to build the unit tests created using the default XCode Unit Test bundle target, it looks like it's stuck on the "Run custom shell script 'Run Script'" phase.

I also notice a high cpu usage on process "otest" to the point where the fans kick in within seconds.

The only useful message I see when expanding the line is

> /Developer/Tools/RunPlatformUnitTests.include:419: note: Running tests for architecture 'i386' (GC OFF)
>   Couldn't open shared capabilities memory GSCapabilities (No such file or directory)

The only option I have at that time is to stop the build.

Have to say I was running unit tests perfectly fine up to this moment but can't say for sure what I did to cause that.

That's on XCode 3.2.4

After updating to 3.2.5 now the run script does fail with an error

> Test rig '/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/Developer/usr/bin/otest' exited abnormally with code 138 (it may have crashed).

Guess they problem is related?
Did find some answers on SO about how exception handling now works differently when using NSInvocation (which otest seems to use) but not really a solution to this.

Comment: I really dislike the built in unit-testing tools that apple provides. I have been using GHUnit for sometime now and really love it. They have a test runner that provides both GUI and command line options. Any existing sen tests will work out of the box with GHUnit. https://github.com/gabriel/gh-unit

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen to me. I made it go away by scrapping my old testing target profile, creating a new one, and pointing all my tests to it. I was too frustrated to compare the profiles line by line to figure out what had changed.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an infinite loop to me. Try adding some NSLog statements and/or debugging your tests with gdb (by adding otest as a custom executable).

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me after updating to Xcode 9 and using script for updating localizable strings file, a minor bug caused the script to never finish. After updating BartyCrouch, everything worked normally.

https://github.com/Flinesoft/BartyCrouch/issues/66